# How can I delete Hotmail emails when using the Gmail app on my phone

Tags: sync, gmail, email, delete, hotmail

I use the Gmail app to read emails on my Android phone. I defined two accounts, a Gmail account and a Hotmail account. The Gmail account works w/o a problem, for syncing, reading, writing and deleting emails.

However, when using the Hotmail account, reading and writing emails work fine, but whenever I delete an email (with any of the various standard methods), the email is removed from Inbox, only to re-appear next time the account syncs (of course, when doing this from the web interface, it works just fine).

I tried a few solutions, including changing the Outlook options and changing settings on my phone, but nothing seems to work.

How can I make my deleted Hotmail emails really disappear?

Answer (score 1):

What do you know... Shortly after posting this, I found a thread in the [Gmail help forum](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/3947624?hl=en&pli=1#) with a solution that worked for me, by user Nico P.

Quoting here, for reference:

> If you look at your folders from your outlook account you'll notice
>   that there is a folder named "Trash" (or another equivalent) and
>   another folder that is the actual folder for deleted emails.
>
> Try to delete this "Trash" folder , it will move it to the actual
>   trash folder (you can then safely deletethis "Trash" folder from here)
>   and sync your Gmail app again. You'll notice that the "Trash" folder
>   is now gone.
>
> Then retry to delete an email. It should work and appear in the
>   "deleted elements" folder.
>
> I think Gmail is programmed to automatically identify the trash folder
>   and when this "Trash" folder is present it's messing up with the real
>   delete action as the "Trash" folder is actually an artefact and not
>   the real one.
>
> Hope it helps, this solution solved my deletion problem.

Note that you don't need to delete the Trash folder. You could just rename it to get the same effect.